# Going to Italy - My 7d needs a wide angle lens

Tags: lens, travel

I'm headed to Italy on my honeymoon.  My current kit (or at least what I'm considering bringing) is as follows:
100L Macro 2.0
18-135 Kit lens
Possibly the 50mm 1.8

Now - I was originally going to buy a big zoom - 100-400ish, but, I'm now considering something very wide for sweeping landscapes.  Because of the crop factor, I have the following questions:

1) is there an high quality (like an L series) wide angle lens that you might recommend in the $1000 range that is far enough from the kit lens so that I won't want to bring the 18-135?

2) Do you think a zoom would be better for Italy, since I can get great shots of architecture and stuff up close - or just use the 55 or the 18 end of the kit lens?

I'm really sort of frozen - paralysis through analysis...
Any thoughts?  If this is too open ended, and it's going to get deleted...my apologies.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not a Canon guy, so take this with all appropriate grains of salt.  I've heard good things about the 17-40 f/4L being a good wide lens that fits in the sub $1k range (about half the price of the 16-35 f/2.8L... and lets face it, you don't shoot landscapes at f/2.8 - there are plenty of comparisons out there between the 17-40 and the 16-35).

Comment: {tongue location=in-cheek} Its also best to get such toys before the significant other says no {/tongue}

Comment: I'd get the 10-22mm. It's great and fun for landscapes. If you don't need ultrawide you could get rid of the 18-135 and get the 17-55mm too.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider Canon's new EF-S 10-18mm, released just a few months ago.
It's really lightweight, has image stabilization (probably only one with IS from your choice.
Optics are really surprisingly good, has less chromatic aberration than 10-22mm.

Build quality is not near L lens (or 10-22mm), but is really ok and seems durable. For it's price (300$) is sure by far best bang for your money, and it will leave you some money in the pocket for other equipment (or honeymoon :) ).

Answer (score 1):

My first thought for about $1000 is to get the 24-105L and leave the kit lens at home. Once you shift from that kit lens to a higher quality lens you'll wonder why you waited.

If you really want to keep the kit lens in your kit, then the Sigma 10-20 is a good idea. I haven't used the Canon 10-22 but have heard good things about it.

Don't forget that if you want to experiment with lenses on the trip or are hesitant about buying something you can rent it (from a place like borrow lenses or lens rentals) and give it a field test, and then choose to buy it if you like it. (or get in the habit of renting stuff you only need occasionally and spend less money on gear...)

Answer (score 0):

The **Canon EF-S 10-22mm f/3.5-4.5 USM** fits your requirements perfectly. It's a great wide-angle range for an EF-S sensor and produces fantastic image quality. I'm looking at UK prices here but at around £400 it should be well within your $1000 budget.

You might also consider the **Sigma 10-20mm f/3.5 EX DC HSM**. I had the previous f/4-5.6 model (which was considerably cheaper than the Canon at the time) and I found the image quality indistinguishable. The new version has the added benefit of being f/3.5 throughout the zoom range.

Both are great lenses and will bag you some fantastic shots. I rarely use a wide-angle for landscapes but love it for creative architecture shots so I'd definitely be packing one for a trip to Italy.

Finally you won't find an actual L series wide angle lens for the 7D, as L lenses are made specifically for full frame sensors. The 17-40 F4 is a great wide-angle lens on a 5D, but on a 7D its range is more like a day-to-day all purpose lens.

Happy honeymoon!